# VBS Delete a folder ? how to pass the value to delete from function?

Tags: vbscript, hta

This is part of my HTA with vbs in it. It browses a directory tree and pick up a folder. then the folder path will be in the textbox `submitted`, then delete that folder by click a button in my HTA. but it keep showing me error @ last line `fso.DeleteFolder(PickFolder_Delete)`
I dont know how to pass the value to `delete` from `function`

```
Sub ChooseCancelFolder_OnClick()
    strStartDir = "\\fs-02\Data\"
    Submitted.txtFile.value = PickFolder_Delete(strStartDir)
End Sub 

Function PickFolder_Delete(strStartDir)
Dim SA, F
Set SA = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set F = SA.BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0, strStartDir)
If (Not F Is Nothing) Then
  PickFolder_Delete = F.Items.Item.path
End If
Set F = Nothing
Set SA = Nothing
End Function 

Sub DeleteAFolder_OnClick()
   Dim fso
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   fso.DeleteFolder(PickFolder_Delete)
End Sub
```

Comment: lol, figured out myself....it should be `fso.DeleteFolder(Submitted.txtFile.value)` ....took me while to figured out....

Comment: You may want to post that as an answer to your own question and accept it (so it counts as a resolved problem).